# Add-Member : Cannot add a member with the name "" because a member with that name already exists

Tags: powershell

When attempting to run script then I got the following the error message.

Error :

```
Add-Member : Cannot add a member with the name "CAllerID*" because a member with that name already exists. To overwrite the member anyway, add the Force parameter to 
your command.
```

Script :

```
    $output = Get-ADUser -Identity user -Properties givenName, sn, displayname, samaccountname, title

$output | Add-Member -membertype noteproperty -name "CAllerID*" -value $null | Export-CSV -Path "c:\tmp\users.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: As the error says: Add `-Force` to the `Add-Member` call to silently overwrite/hide any existing member

Comment: At this time  I can not get any output. There is no any entry inside CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-Force` and `-PassThru` to the `Add-Member` call:

- `-Force` ensures any existing conflicting properties are overwritten
- `-PassThru` causes `Add-Member` to output the modified input object

```
$output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CAllerID*" -Value $null -Force -PassThru | Export-CSV -Path "c:\tmp\users.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

If you want to further trim the property set returned by `Get-ADUser`, use `Select-Object`:

```
$output | Select-Object -Property givenName,sn,displayName,SAMAccountName,Title | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CAllerID*" -Value $null -Force -PassThru | Export-CSV -Path "c:\tmp\users.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Now , I am getting "CAllerID*","DisplayName","DistinguishedName","Enabled","GivenName","Name","ObjectClass","ObjectGUID","SamAccountName","SID","sn","Surname","Title","UserPrincipalName""  column inside CSV file. So I mean there are  unnecessary columns inside CSV file. Only I want to export CAllerID*,givenName, sn, displayname, samaccountname, title columns.

Comment: @Arbelac `$output | Select-Object <the properties you want> | Export-Csv ...`